# Java EOF Exception during fetching of data from MySQL with volly , Json Object

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I don't know what happened .. My application was working fine but now Im getting this error.. I havent change any thing in code.

Im trying to fetch data from Volly but getting Java Eofexception .. here is my  function

```
private void getData() {

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    String uid = ConfirmActivity.Img_path;


    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Almost done","now Fetching your result...",false,false);

    String url = AppConfig.DATA_URL+uid;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String disease="";
    String date_time;
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        disease = collegeData.getString(KEY_DISEASE);
        date_time = collegeData.getString(KEY_DATETIME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            disease, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    Disease_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_dname);
    diseases = disease;
    Disease_name.setText(disease);

}
```

Here is my php side code:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $uid  = $_GET['uid'];

    require_once 'include/DB_Conn.php';

    $sql = "SELECT result,date_time FROM detected_disease WHERE image_path='".$uid."' and status IS NULL ORDER BY dd_id DESC limit 1";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE detected_disease SET status = 1 WHERE image_path='".$uid."' ORDER BY dd_id DESC limit 1";

    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $result = array();

    array_push($result,array(
        "result"=>$res['result'],
        "date_time"=>$res['date_time']
        )
    );

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

    mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

There is no error in android monitor and there is not clue that how this error is happening..
I have searched similar types of error but i haven't found any clue.
i have also checked the value my app sending to api... which is ok..

Secondly.. this php code is working fine in browser .. giving expected result.

Kindly please help..
Thx

Comment: what do you mean there is not error in monitor? then where did you get this error? post full stacktrace

Comment: this code was working ok when i last tried.. but now its giving me this error!

Comment: there is no stack trace or any thing in android monitor.

Comment: so i assume it's displayed on the `Toast` you need to add a code in `onErrorResponse()` to view full error stacktrace using object `VolleyError error` not only `getMessage()`

Comment: ok, let me try.

Comment: i think its better to `Log` that, don't show full stack in Toast, it might be so big, and it's not meant to be done :)

Comment: yeah.. ur right :)